# .NET v6.0 LTS vs .NET v7.0 STS

Tags: asp.net-core, webforms, asp.net-core-6.0, .net-framework-version, asp.net-core-7.0

**"I'm seeking guidance for my first .NET project, deciding between .NET LTS and .NET STS, with a background in ASP.NET WebForms, and I'm curious about insights and potential drawbacks of using the .NET Standard Term Support version."**

As I embark on my first .NET project, I'm seeking advice on choosing between .NET LTS and .NET STS. I have a solid understanding of ASP.NET WebForms and want to ensure compatibility and efficiency in my development process.

Could you share your insights on which version would be more suitable for someone familiar with ASP.NET WebForms? Additionally, are there any potential disadvantages or considerations I should be aware of when working with the .NET Standard Term Support version?

Your expertise is highly valued, and I appreciate your guidance on this matter.

Comment: How about .NET 8 released just now? :) It's also LTS.

Comment: Is that mean now DOT NET Core 7 is now a LTS version too.

Comment: No. 7 is still standard support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTS versions are supported for a longer period (usually 3 years), making them a safer choice for long-term projects.They receive critical bug fixes and security updates throughout their lifecycle.LTS versions are more stable and have been tested extensively in various environments.

STS versions include the latest features and improvements. They are updated more frequently, offering access to new technologies and tools.Typically supported for about 18 months, STS versions require more frequent updates to newer versions to stay supported.

The newer .NET versions have significant differences in how web applications are structured and managed.Check for compatibility of any libraries or dependencies you plan to use. Some older libraries used in ASP.NET WebForms might not be compatible with the latest .NET versions.

Summary is for a stable, long-term project Choose .NET LTS. If you want to use the latest features and willing to update often you can go with .NET STS.

Comment: Thank you sir.. I'm gonna lay my hands on .NET Core 6.0 LTS

Answer (score 0):

To anyone getting to this Stackoverflow question, regarding the answer "long-term project Choose .NET LTS. If you want to use the latest features and willing to update often you can go with .NET STS.", this is a very outdated way of thinking.

Almost always use latest version of .NET regardless of STS or LTS, sticking to LTS only is hardly worth it or viable in most cases and most times show the company is not flexible or handling their updates push properly.

Aside from the period that the LTS gets patched compared to a STS version, LTS for 3 years and STS 18 months, there is no further benefit to LTS.
More importantly you officially you even need to use the latest version as well for proper support regarding security issue's, and even some .NET issues itself.
This means as of current writing, if you use 8.0.1 instead of the latest 8.0.2 LTS you are no longer using the supported LTS and need to update.

There are a few where LTS is unavoidable, like when you create a Library for developers to target and support broad audience, and using Azure Functions with in-process mode which only supports LTS.

But otherwise always use the latest .NET version. If someone gives you a reason that it not possible, or recommended, especially with services and products, it means the company does not have its product and support in order. Because if you cannot provide an update at least once a year that also has .net update than there is something wrong.